# Dynamic database record in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am making an iphone application in which there is use of database. But this database records must be dynamic means record get stored in database when user make entry in iphone application. It need dynamic record.

Anyone know about it? Please help me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: can you elaborate the dynamic record part a little bit

Comment: Dynamic part like.. Name of patient, frequency of medicine, doctor's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLite DB. Which is mostly used for iPhone application in build Data Base.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to choose to use SQLite, [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is almost always a better choice.